# Combine multiple lists into one organized csv using bs4

Tags: python, html, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to this, I am using this as a learning opportunity, and have only gotten this far due to this communities help. But, I am trying to grab multiple sections pages like this

https://m.the-numbers.com/movie/Black-Panther

specifically the `summary`, `starring cast`, and `supporting cast`

I have been successful writing 1 list to csv, but cannot seem to find a way to write multiple. I am looking for a solution that is scalable, where I can keep adding more lists to the export.

things I have tried:

putting them in separate lists such as `details, actors`, using the same list with `details.extended`, etc. and nothing seems to work.

Expected result is producing a table such as:

HEADERS:
    `title, amount,starName,StarCharacter`

with the data listed underneath.

ERRORS:
    `Exception has occurred: AttributeError'str' object has no attribute 'keys'`

````
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import re

# Making get request
r = requests.get('https://m.the-numbers.com/movie/Black-Panther')

# Creating BeautifulSoup object
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

# Localizing table from the BS object
table_soup = soup.find('div', class_='row').find('div', class_='table-responsive').find('table', id='movie_finances')
website = 'https://m.the-numbers.com/'
details = []
# Iterating through all trs in the table except the first(header) and the last two(summary) rows 

for tr in table_soup.find_all('tr')[2:4]:
    tds = tr.find_all('td')

    # Creating dict for each row and appending it to the details list
    details.extend({
        'title': tds[0].text.strip(),
        'amount': tds[1].text.strip(),
    })


cast_soup = soup.find('div', id='accordion').find('div', class_='cast_new').find('table', class_='table table-sm')
for tr in cast_soup.find_all('tr')[2:15]:
    tdc = tr.find_all('td')

    # Creating dict for each row and appending it to the details list
    details.append({
        'starName': tdc[0].text.strip(),
        'starCharacter': tdc[1].text.strip(),
    })

# Writing details list of dicts to file using csv.DictWriter
with open('moviesPage2018.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='\n') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=details[0].keys())
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(details)```
````

Comment: can I use too pandas?

Comment: And It is not clear to me which labels you get the amount and the title..the amount is the sum of the "Latest Ranking on Cumulative Box Office Lists" table??

Comment: So it breaks it into a table, so amount is the actual numbers, title is the title of the class of numbers meaning title pulls “Domestic Gross”, “international Gross”, “Worldwide” . Amount pulls “$7000000” etc, and that actually worlds when I run it by itself.